# Laravel validation input based on other user inputs

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4

I have a form for submitting categories. ( new , edit )

```
<form ... >
    <input type="text" name="name" />

    <select name="parent_id" >
        <option value="0" >Root</option>
        <option value="1" >Computer</option>
        <option value="..." >...</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

each one of ids in parent_id is a category id in database except for 0, root;

I want to have a validation which says: check parent_id to be a valid id in category table if it is not 0. ( 0 is root and not an id in database )

How can I do that with laravel validation rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not used Sometimes before. But please try below. Not currently able to test myself.

```
/* This is untested code  */

$validation->sometimes('parent_id', 'exists:categories', function($input)
{
    return $input->parent_id > 0;
});

/* This is untested code.*/
```

Manual Entry: http://laravel.com/docs/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = Input::only('dragon', 'parent_id', 'carrot');

$rules = [
    // your rules
];

if ( ! empty($input['parent_id']))
{
    $rules['parent_id'] = 'exists:categories';
}

// the normal validation stuff here
```

http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-exists

Comment: this does not help. exists with conditions based on other inputs.